# Cambiar el nombre al paquete de mi proyecto en Android Studio

Tags: android

me pasaron un proyecto para Android Studio, con un nombre "ejemplo001" tanto la carpeta donde se encuentra el proyecto, como internamente el código interno lleva ese nombre, como puedo cambiarlo de nombre por ejemplo "Programa X"

Sigo estos pasos, pero no se cambian todos los nombres internamente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

Para renombrar el nombre del paquete, puedes realizarlo como indicas

botón derecho en paquete > `Refactor` > `Rename`, en algunos casos aparecera la siguiente ventana:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

indica la confirmación para refactorizar el paquete en esas incidencias.

Para finalizar revisa dentro de tus archivos `build.gradle` de la aplicación, la propiedad  `applicationId` que tienes que cambiar manualmente.

**Este método únicamente funciona para el último segmento del paquete.**

Comment: Hola, no me refiero al nombre que aparece en la aplicaicon cuando se instala, si no al nombre que pongo marcados en la imagen de arriba en el apartado **java**

Comment: @SoCu ok te refieres al package name, he actualizado la respuesta.

Comment: Hora si Jorgesys, pero se cambia parte del nombre, no todo.
por ejemplo si se llama com.example.cannie.ejemplo001; lo he renombrado y pasa a llamarse com.example.cannie.programaxx.
la primera parte no se cambia **com.example.cannie**
luego he visto que en la carpeta del proyecto hay un archivo *.iml* que sigue con el nombre anterior. 
  
Por cierto, como soy nuevo en este foro, no se si es normal, pero se recibien notificaciones por corre de nuevas respuestas ? yo no las recibo.

Comment: Por otro lado no se porque me salen aqui en el foro todo el texto seguido, le pongo dos espacios detras  

Luego pulso la tecla mayusculas + intro para bajar una linea, pero parece no con funciona.